# Как добавить аналог "cmd" или "powershell" в систему

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

Если нажать `Win + R` и ввести `cmd` винда сразу открывает консоль. Моя цель сделать аналог такого ввода для другого приложения.

Добавление файла в `%PATH%` не дало результата.

Comment: В %PATH% нужно добавлять не файл, а каталог

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте соответствующий ключ в реестр:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` для общесистемной регистрации
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` для текущего пользователя

У указанного ключа следует создать подключ, в котором значением по умолчанию будет команда для запуска (не забудьте про кавычки если в пути есть пробелы!)

Так, если вам нужно запускать `vcpkg` по пути `C:\Program Files\vcpkg-2023.04.15\vcpkg.exe`, можно добавить ключ `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\vcpkg.exe` со значением по умолчанию `"C:\Program Files\vcpkg-2023.04.15\vcpkg.exe"`.

Если не нравится редактировать реестр через GUI - можно использовать файл экспорта реестра (это текстовый файл с расширением .reg, создать его можно любым текстовым редактором):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\vcpkg.exe]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\vcpkg-2023.04.15\\vcpkg.exe\""
```

Подробности: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration

Comment: Сработало. Приложение действительно теперь запускается через `Win + R` или индексируется в поиске. Но в PowerShell вызов `vcpkg` всё ещё не работает (что является моей конечной целью). Я регистрировал приложение как вручную, так и через предложеный .reg

Comment: @Naxel PowerShell на эти ключи не смотрит, тут только PATH

Comment: @Naxel можете также попробовать настроить [псевдоним](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-7.3) в [профиле](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3), только не забудьте про [политики исполнения](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Спасибо. Добился результата такой коммандой в PowerShell: 
`New-Alias -Name vcpkg -Value $env:ProgramFiles\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe` (были траблы из-за пробела в пути)